# Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed when deploying with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am using Capistrano to deploy a Rails app to a linux server. When I run any Capistrano task I get the following error:

```
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user adam@example.com
```

I am using Capistrano 2.15.5 and net-ssh 2.9.1. I am deploying to a fresh linux server which has two users: root and adam. I have the following in deploy.rb:

```
set :user, "adam"
set :password, "my_password"
```

The above error only occurs when I am trying to deploy as the user adam, I can deploy as the user root. Therefore I think this may be related to linux setup/permissions rather than capistrano setup. I am not sure where the problem is, can anyone help with this?

Many thanks,

Adam

Comment: I strongly suggest you remove all trace of passwords from your deploy scripts, create some SSH keys, and configure SSH agent forwarding if you're deploying from GitHub or another remote repository. It would also be prudent to disable password-authentication on your server. It's quite insecure.

Comment: @AdamP  What is your net-ssh gem version? if it is not 2.7.0. try to change to that version and try once

Comment: SOLVED - thanks anusha, changing net-ssh to 2.7.0 did the trick

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ensure that you can SSH to the server as the deploy user. Once you can do that, make sure you can access the deploy directories and create files etc within them.

Once that's all working, Capistrano has some deploy tasks specifically designed to check you have all of the prerequisite permissions in place. Run them.

After that you should be good to go.

From the error you've pasted, it looks like you're lacking the basic access rights to simply log in via SSH with the username/password combination you're using.

As per my comment to your question - you should seriously consider dropping the passwords in favour of SSH keys.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I agree that this does look like I'm lacking basic access rights - what is strange is that I can SSH into the server as the user adam without any problems. Also I can deploy with capistrano using the user root, and don't get this error. Do you have any idea what permissions I might need to look at? I am not sure where to start!